# Are there weapon requirements for executing?

Tags: torchlight-2

What are the weapon requirements for executing? Must both weapons be of the same types? That is, I have to dual wield 2x swords, or 2x maces, but not a sword and an axe?

Comment: The have to be the same types, and I think that's the only restriction.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The rule is very simple, these combinations provide a chance to `Execute`:

- Melee + melee
- Ranged + ranged
- Magic + magic

The last 2 basically means you can use a `Pistol + Pistol` to Execute, but not a Pistol + Wand. You would need a `Wand + Wand` combination to have a chance on Execute.

So you can use `Sword + Axe` or `Sword + Claw` and they will all give you a chance to Execute.

You can easily verify this by opening the `Arcane statistics` and looking what your Execution Chance is. If you have a combination that has no chance on Execute it will show you that you have a 0% chance to Execute.